# how to find crud repository functions implementation?

Tags: java, repository, crud

How or where can I find what the HQL querys of functions declared in crud repository intrface looks like? I am especially interested in the function `Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);`. I do not want to just use it and print it with some example entity.

Answer (score 0):

Hi At the time of executing your code you will be get the complete query which is hide behind that function.

Comment: as explained in question: ``i dont want just use it and print it with some example entiti.``